# How to close get image from page in Perl

Tags: perl

Using the following code:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $url= "http://example.com";
my $html= get $url;
```

I am able to get the source in $html variable, and when I echo out the variable, it does have the code. I am wondering how would I save one of the images on that page to my folder called images in the same folder where this file is now? I am getting to that page through `my $IE->Navigate($url);` method.

I tried using Image::Grab module, but it wouldn't install without force (no idea how to do that).

Comment: do you want to load all images from page?

Comment: "won't install without force" means "Something has gone wrong and it is broken so it won't be installed. You can force it to install if you know that what has gone wrong isn't a real problem". What has gone wrong usually *is* a problem and you should look at the errors output doing the install attempt to find out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, parse the HTML using an appropriate module (I tend towards [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath)).

Second, use its API to find the `<img>` element you care about and extract its URI.

Third, convert that URI to an absolute one with [URI](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) if needed.

Fourth, use the `getstore` method from LWP::Simple to save it.